# Complex conditional statement in Android XML data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to do a ternary statement in XML data binding as in Google's example (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/), but it keep giving me `invalid token` error when running

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text='@{ obj.fields[0].unit == null
            ? obj.fields[0].displayName
            : obj.fields[0].displayName + " (" + obj.fields[0].unit + ")"}' />
```

Basically I am binding text to a single field in the model. If it doesn't have unit, just show its name, otherwise put the unit in parenthesis after the name. Where have I done wrong?

Comment: can you please give more details on what you are expecting

Comment: I have never done data-binding before, but wouldn't it make sense if your Model class has a public getter which handles the nullcheck and string formatting? so this way you can do `android:text='@{ obj.fields[0].MySuperCoolMethod(); }`

Comment: IMHO, something that complex should not be in a binding expression. Add a `<variable>` for some sort of presenter that can implement your algorithm, then have a binding expression call that method on that presenter.

Comment: @CommonsWare, haven't used presenter before, do you mind show some code? Thanks!

Comment: It's just an object. Have it hold onto whatever `obj.fields[0]` is. Give it a method like `getDisplayName()` that contains your algorithm. Add a second `<variable>` for this object and bind it when you are binding whatever `obj` is. Change your binding expression to call `getDisplayName()` on this new object.